# What organizations use CiviCRM?

Tags: civicontribute

Okay...call me blind, but I can't find a list anywhere of who is using CiviCRM. I know it exists somewhere (or at least an outdated form of it). Can anyone help me...?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the page you're talking about, but I don't think it survived the website redesign. Here is a list of CiviCRM Members though, which has the more high-profile names you're probably searching for: https://civicrm.org/members

Comment: There are three entries for the National Democratic Institute at that members link - one member with three memberships maybe? Also, could the list be in alphabetic order, would be easier to scan.  And yeah my organization is not yet on it, so I need to fix that :)

Comment: I think the address to share stuff like that is info@civicrm.org. I'm just your average community member.

Comment: Nicholai, right, will do